# What is correct way to use "Habe ich" and "Ich habe"? please help me with this

Tags: sentence-structure

I am waaay to much confused about this and this is apparently way too easy

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Habe ich”
Its used in questions that are about you in your perspectiv or as a (elliptical) answer. Its like a "Do I...?" or "I did..."

For example:

> Habe ich etwas falsch gemacht?
>
> Did i do something wrong?

or

> Somebody: Hast du den Müll rausgebracht?
>
> You: Ja, habe ich.
>
> Somebody:Did you bring out the trash?
>
> You:Yes I did.

“Ich habe”
Its used to if its a statement about you in your perspectiv Its like a "I have..." or "I'm...".

For example:

> Ich habe Hunger.
>
> I'm hungry.

or

> Ich habe 3 Äpfel.
>
> I have 3 apples.

Edit: Thanks to @HagenvonEitzen for correcting me.

Comment: Note that (and perhaps this is the confusing part)  "Habe ich" can be used as a (elliptical) *answer*, i.e., as a statement: "Hast du den Müll raus gebracht?" - "Ja, habe ich" (and not "Ja, ich habe")

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True... I corect my answer.